# How to check if all elements of a list contain an expression, with 'MatchQ' or otherwise

Tags: pattern-matching

Sorry, I am new user of patterns. I thought that the check:

```
MatchQ[{-y \[Gamma], -y z }, {__?Times[y, __]}]
```

would produce `True`, since all elements of the list contain `y`, but the result is `False`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)
```

In a [`PatternTest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html) the test must be a boolean expression that evaluates to `True` or `False`, not a pattern

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

To test if **every** element is a product containing `y`

```
AllTrue[{-y γ, -a y z}, MatchQ[#, Times[y, __]] &]

(* True *)

AllTrue[{-y γ, -a z}, MatchQ[#, Times[y, __]] &]

(* False *)
```

To test the individual elements

```
MatchQ[#, Times[y, __]] & /@ {-y γ, -a z}

(* {True, False} *)
```

To test if **any** element is a product containing `y`

```
Or @@ (MatchQ[#, Times[y, __]] & /@ {-y γ, -a z})

(* True *)

MatchQ[{-y γ, -a z}, _?(! FreeQ[#, y] &)]

(* True *)

MatchQ[{-γ, -a z}, _?(! FreeQ[#, y] &)]

(* False *)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write a detailed explanation.

Comment: Wouldn't a simple `MemberQ` be easier for the last examples? `MatchQ` with `_?(test)` seems like a very complicated way to evaluate `test`

Comment: @Lukas - Yes I was overly focused at looking at different ways to use `MatchQ`. The actual problem with the last two cases is that they just look for the presence of `y` rather than `y`'s presence in a product as is done in the other cases.